# What is the function of Switch Processor (symbol)?

Tags: switch

I see this symbol very often on topologies, what does it mean and why needs an IP apart from the switch itself?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is most often a module in a larger router/multi-layer switch, symbolizing the switch part. The exact meaning may vary though, and we'd need much more context for a more concrete answer.